# Vue.js v-bind has a delay, form submits before value is changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm trying to update a hidden input with an entered value from a SweetAlert modal (basically a prompt).

The code below does not work, the form submits but the hidden field `value` is **null**.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="input" v-model="value">
```

JavaScript:

```
this.value = websiteId;
event.target.submit();
```

The below code however does seem to work! But not really much point in using Vue.js if i'm going to just plain old JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" class="input-value-web" name="input" value="0">
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('.input-value-web').value = websiteId;
event.target.submit();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you change the value of a Vue instance's data property, like you're doing with `this.value = websiteId`, that bound property won't update the value of the `<input>` until the Vue instance's next update.

However, the next update won't occur until after everything in the method has been executed.

To get around this, use the [`$nextTick` method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) to wait until the Vue instance has updated before executing `event.target.submit()`.

Here's an example:

```
methods: {
  submitForm() {
    this.value = websiteId;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      event.target.submit();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, did not know that! Thanks, will mark as answer.

Comment: This is a very tricky thing unless you understand the internals of Vue well. This answer saved me. Was tricky to even search for. Thanks!